# search into subcategories plugin subcategory value not come

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Currently, I am using **https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-into-subcategories/** plugin on that first I select categories dropdown then subcategories dropdown but value not come on subcategories.

[image]

Comment: It seems like plugin issue that you are using as reported here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/3rd-level-doesnt-work/

Comment: I already reported to plugin author but still they not response.

Comment: Someone, please help me on this.

Comment: facing same issue..... hope someone fix that.